# Trigger events after an API call

Tags: events, apache-kafka

I have an API call ,let's say it is a form submission . After the submission I want to trigger few events let's say

->I want to Email the user who filled the form

->I want to analyze that form response with a bunch of other data

-> Send notification to the admin

Like this I might have n events to trigger based on the specific form (There could be many types of forms and I want to trigger based on the form submitted). How do I do this ?

Initially I thought of having all logic to execute these triggers in a util file and based on the form I will run these functions . But I could sense that It would not scale well . Then I found Kafka and thought that I could fit in my use case.

I could have all the triggers as a topic and in the consumer I will have the logic to execute each of these topics . Once the form is filled ,the producer i.e the form API will send the message(form data) to all the topic it has subscribed to and Kafka will take care of the rest .

Does this sound like a good solution or I'm just re-inventing the wheel ? Also If new triggers keep coming, like I have request from my client(human XD) to do so and so validations/analyze when his form is submitted , how do I efficiently add the logic to handle that trigger in the consumer API .

P.S Or do I need to think of a distributed system to handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, your HTTP server can do whatever it wants on form submission, including calling remote HTTP services rather than use any queue. But since Kafka is asynchronous, it may not be best used for request-reply payloads such as form validation.

You don't "add consumer triggers" in your producer code. You produce to topics, and that's it. Consumers poll from the topics you've configured them for, and process data accordingly, irregardless of what produced into those topics

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate ! . Regarding validation it's not actually a form validation. By validation I meant some sort of decision analysis based on that response and not conventional form validation .
I could do remote HTTP calls but let's have after submission I have to do 5-10 analysis or triggers basically ,in such cases I'm worried about the performance .

Are there any other alternatives for  this microservices /distributed system would they be of any help ? . Your inputs would be really helpful

Comment: There's gRPC and Twirp, but you'd have similar scaling limitations

Comment: Um so which one should I go for .As you mentioned I am not expecting for any reply from the remote HTTP call , I just need to trigger a bunch of functions ,I'm not expecting their reply and I should not increase the latency of my primary form submission HTTP call.
Example , Once my form is saved in my database , I trigger all my required functions in ~O(1) time and I don't wait for their reply and I end the HTTP call . But the triggered functions should be executed properly . Only for this purpose I chose Kafka . Am I doing anything wrong here ? . Please let me know